# How to write a proper generic function signature when borrowing data across multiple traits

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime, borrowing

While developing on a private project I ran into a lifetime problem related to borrowing the same object over multiple structs and traits. This is a bunch of stripped-down definitions I used:

```rust
trait WorkspaceLog {
    fn get(&self) -> usize;
}

struct TheLog<'a>(&'a FilesystemOverlay);

impl<'a> WorkspaceLog for TheLog<'a> {
    fn get(&self) -> usize {
        (self.0).0
    }
}

trait WorkspaceController<'a> {
    type Log: WorkspaceLog;
    fn get_log(&'a self) -> Self::Log;
}

struct FilesystemOverlay(usize);

struct FSWorkspaceController<'a>(&'a mut FilesystemOverlay);

impl<'a> WorkspaceController<'a> for FSWorkspaceController<'a> {
    type Log = TheLog<'a>;

    fn get_log(&'a self) -> Self::Log {
        TheLog(&*self.0)
    }
}

trait AsWorkspaceController<'a> {
    type Controller: WorkspaceController<'a>;

    fn get_controller(self) -> Self::Controller;
}

impl<'a> AsWorkspaceController<'a> for &'a mut FilesystemOverlay {
    type Controller = FSWorkspaceController<'a>;

    fn get_controller(self) -> FSWorkspaceController<'a> {
        FSWorkspaceController(self)
    }
}
```

So far, so good. This basically enables me to borrow a mut ref of FilesystemOverlay as some other interface, providing additional functionality. This interface, in turn, allows me to borrow essentially the same thing as yet another thing that provides the final data. This works as long a I directly use FilesystemOverlay:

```rust
fn init1(control_dir: &mut FilesystemOverlay) -> usize {
    let controller = control_dir.get_controller();
    let log = controller.get_log();
    log.get()
}
```

However, if I replace the concrete reference with a type parameter, the compilation fails, telling me that controller doesn't live long enough since it, for reasons I don't understand, thinks that get_log borrows controller beyond the end of the function and thus way longer than the program logic
requires:

```rust
fn init2<'a: 'b, 'b, O>(control_dir: O) -> usize
    where O: AsWorkspaceController<'b>+'a {
    let controller = control_dir.get_controller();
    let log = controller.get_log();
    log.get()
}

fn main() {
    let mut control_dir = FilesystemOverlay(5);
    dbg!(init1(&mut control_dir));
    dbg!(init2(&mut control_dir));
}
```

I tried several approaches but I so far were unable to figure out the proper signature of init2. This is the error I get:

```
error[E0597]: `controller` does not live long enough
  --> test.rs:53:15
   |
53 |     let log = controller.get_log();
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
54 |     log.get()
55 | }
   | - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'b as defined on the function body at 50:18...
  --> test.rs:50:18
   |
50 | fn init2<'a: 'b, 'b, O>(control_dir: O) -> usize
   |                  ^^

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.
```

This is the full code on the [rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a2ef98efb581a6819f41eeb391d822f9).

So, how do I need to change the signature of init2 so that the compiler understands that controller may be dropped after the call to log.get()? Do I need other changes in the above types as well?

**Edit:** I've made some additional experiments and [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=deb828422637e1f9cbca4fa573425ef0) is the closest I could manage to create. This one has two lifetimes and a signature that late-binds, but it still gives a warning about UB. Does anyone understand why?

Comment: Must `WorkspaceController::get_log` borrow self, or can it take ownership?

Comment: Thanks @eggyal for the suggestion! Yes, this will lead to a usable version of the code (something along [these](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1f0f5d2d6e41d5687098e5030e81437f) lines) but requires a change of an already-existing trait plus all call sites which is something I'd rather like to avoid. However, I'll give it a try in my project, maybe this leads to even better code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of a nice and knowing person on GitHub I was able to create a working version of the code, see https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/58868. The key was to use a free lifetime bound on the type declaration of `Controller` inside `AsWorkspaceController`:

```rust
trait AsWorkspaceController<'a> {
    type Controller: for<'b> WorkspaceController<'b>+'a;

    fn get_controller(&'a mut self) -> Self::Controller;
}
```

See the full code on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=33dd6ea59255870d5db57054140b4e2f).